# Why is Set object split string?

Tags: javascript, string, set

```js
const set = new Set("123");

console.log(set);
```

Output is "Set { '1', '2', '3' }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Set` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) takes [an iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) and takes every value of it.

Strings [have an `@@iterator` property by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) which makes them iterable:

```js
const foo = "xyz";

console.log(...foo);

const [a, b, c] = foo;
console.log(a, b, c);

for (const char of foo)
  console.log(char);
```

Therefore, this is exactly what happens when you pass a string to a `Set` constructor - it draws every value just as it would with any other iterable:

```js
const foo = "xyz";
const bar = [1, 2, 3]

console.log("set of string:", new Set(foo));
console.log("set of array :", new Set(bar));
```

```html
<h1>Check the browser console</h1>
```

Comment: Good answer! I like how you demonstrate the iterability of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Because strings are [*iterable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), and when you give [the `Set` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) an iterable object,¹ it loops through the values provided by the object's iterator and adds them to the set. In the case of strings, the [string iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) iterates the strings *code points* — in your example, `"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"`. (For more about "code points" vs. "code units" and what a string is, read [my blog post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/01/26/what-is-a-string/).)

If you want to add a string to a set, you have to do add separately or wrap it in another iterable (like an array):

```js
// Add separately:
let set = new Set();
set.add("123");
console.log(set.size); // 1
console.log([...set]); // ["123"]

// Or wrap:
set = new Set(["123"]);
console.log(set.size); // 1
console.log([...set]); // ["123"]
```

---

¹ (or a primitive such as a string that coerces to an iterable object)